Useful Search Terms To Find Crossband-Capable Mobile Transceiver
Referring to Building a portable event repeater what criteria should I use to search for a crossband-capable transceiver? Specifically, what terms do I use with places like Ham Radio Outlet, Gigaparts, and so on? I'm not talking about a web search.
One of our local repeaters is on a temporary antenna, and is running low power (W. Newberry MA).
Charles W1CAF

I’d like to suggest a slightly different approach:
Use a Google/web search to identify the rig(s) that meet your criteria. I suggest doing this first because it’s going to be a relatively small set.
Now, with the two or three matching rigs in mind, you don’t need to figure out how to manipulate several different merchant search systems, you can simply plug-in the manufacturer and model number at each merchant for price comparisons.

This is a rather interesting, but broad question, because search engines work fundamentally different for different people. I can virtually guarantee that the first page of google search results for any technical term will look very different than someone else's. People try to insist that is not the case, and that searching for a term will yield the basically same results up top. It does not (hence, "google this term alone yourself" is almost universally bad advice; you always need to help people by pointing them at the right type of resources. For some things, wikipedia is the right source, for the other, ham forums). This is exacerbated by the fact that significant amounts of worthless machine-generated, unchecked websites now clutter search results, and these are prone to just amplifying widely held but overly simplifying (or plain wrong) preconceptions.
Anyways.

Define the actual bands you want to work with. These are your most important search terms.
Define the modes you want to work; nearly as important

this has fundamental effects on what kind of relay you can build. It's easy to relay digital packetized modes that are short and "bursty" (you can collect packets on both bands, then switch from receive to transmit mode, and transmit the "buffered" packets, without having to worry about your sensitive receiver getting fried to a light-brown teint by your own transmitter), it's harder to relay wideband continuous transmission on close-by bands


as described above, define whether your transceiver needs to be full duplex or half duplex.

And:
You don't seem to be afraid of software! That is a great thing. There's projects like openrepeater that might connect to existing receivers and transmitters to build cross-band repeaters. I really don't like their website much, as it leaves one completely in the dark about what kind of hardware is supported, but you can figure it out via their forums.

Narrowed original question.

@octopusgrabbus ah, nice! Yeah, then the same functional aspects still apply, but my first paragraph: just forget about it :)
